# How is code organized in the ABP framework?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have some doubts about organizing code. I see two ways of organizing code: `package by layer` and `package by component`.
http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/2015/03/08/package_by_component_and_architecturally_aligned_testing.html

The ABP framework itself does not require a specific form to be adopted, and both forms appear to be supported.
Only `package by layer` can be seen in the sample given by ABP framework. It is not clear whether `package by component` can be used.

For example, there are three boundary contexts: order, product and customer.

If `package by layer` is used, it will be as shown in the figure below.

```
Project.sln  
  Project.Application  
    OrderContext
    ProductContext
    CustomerContext
  Project.Core  
    OrderContext
    ProductContext
    CustomerContext
  Project.EntityFrameworkCore
    ...
```

If `package by component` is used, it will be as shown in the figure below.

```
Project.sln  
  hosts  
    Project.Host
  modules
    orders
      Order.Application
      Order.Core
      Order.EntityFrameworkCore
    products
      Product.Application
      Product.Core
      Product.EntityFrameworkCore
    customers
      Customer.Application
      Customer.Core
      Customer.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Which method is more widely used in the ABP framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Boilerplate uses `package by layer` or "Domain Driven Design Layers".
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/NLayer-Architecture

Here is the folder structure of the official template downloadable at https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates with the source code hosted at https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template:

```
AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.sln
src/
  AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Application/
    Authorization/
    Configuration/
    MultiTenancy/
    Roles/
    Users/
  AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/
    Authorization/
      Roles/
      Users/
    Configuration/
    MultiTenancy/
```

Comment: @SAssassin Read the rest of the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I think I found the answer.
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1476#issuecomment-277330004
ABP framework can be ```package by components``` and has been embodied in ABP vNext.